# Can I use a plugin on a django cms page that already has an app hook?

Tags: python, django, hook, django-cms

I attach a Django app to a CMS page by using the Advanced settings menu and adding the app to the page as an app hook. By default plugins that I add to this page are ignored.

I would like to have CMS editable text / content on the same page as well in order to be more flexible than just editing the app's code all the time. Is there a way to do so EXCEPT for turning the app into a plugin itself.

Intuitively I am looking for something that would display CMS plugins inside my app. Is this possible? If so, can somebody hand me a starting point (probably right part of the documentation). I just found [this](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending_cms/app_integration.html#integration-apphooks) from the django cms documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use {% static_placeholder my_name %} templatetags in your app templates. Or you can use a placeholder field in your app models.

Comment: ok thx. sounds like this is the concept I was looking for. Can I fill the placeholders with cms stacks? Or how would this work? Can you recommend a good read?